EnergyPlus FMU: Begin day as an input
I'm reusing an EnergyPlus model made by a colleague and creating an FMU to develop a reduced order model from it. I would also like to use a variation of this model to simulate the system in a loop with a controller.
I noticed that for constant Direct and Diffuse radiation inputs the heat absorbed by the outer walls changes depending on the time of the day and the month. If the results vary with the day of the year I can't simulate a day or a time-step accurately. I don't want to simulate the entire year each time I run the program.
I would like to simulate one specific day of the year without changing the Run Period parameters of the idf. Is there any way to set these parameters as Inputs for the FMU?
Thank you!
